# Javascript resource not loading in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I have a whole bunch of javascript files I need to load in order. However, one of them is not loading in ie7.

Here's the function that does the loading:

```
function loadScript(url, callback){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;

    // Attach handlers for all browsers
    var done = false;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
            if( !done && ( !this.readyState 
                                    || this.readyState == "loaded" 
                                    || this.readyState == "complete") )
            {
                    done = true;

                    // Continue your code
                    callback();

                    // Handle memory leak in IE
                    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    head.removeChild( script );
            }
    };

    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

And the function calls:

```
loadScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js',function(){
    loadScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js',function(){
        loadScript('http://XXX/js/data.php?rand='+Math.random(),function(){
            loadScript('http://XXX/js/jquery.inject.js?rand='+Math.random(),function(){
                console.log('a');
                loadScript('XXX/js/press.js?rand='+Math.random(),function(){
                    console.log('b');
                    inject_press();
                });

            });
        });
    });
});
```

The file that doesn't load i jquery.inject.js, whos code is

```
console.log('y');

jQuery.prototype.inject = function(a){
    ...
}
```

Again this works in all browsers **except** ie7. The output is

```
a
b
```

Comment: http://blog.andrewcantino.com/blog/2008/11/23/replacement-for-script-onload-in-ie/

Comment: The onloads do fire, not the console.log()s for 'a' and 'b', which are tucked in the callbacka

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way how to load ECMAscript files. I would name that files to sort them and then load [using ASP.NET 4.5 bundling](http://theshravan.net/bundling-and-minification-support-in-asp-net-mvc-4/).

Comment: bundling would definitely be advisable but the OP didn't mention that he was using IIS or 4.5 (not yet released) for that matter.